# Error when attempting to use st_distance_sphere to filter rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, polygon

I have a table with `polygon` geometries. I am attempting to filter rows based on proximity to a point.

I am using `st_distance_sphere` to calculate distance and filters rows: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)

For a snapshot of mysql table, it's contents and what I am attempting to do, check out this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e8bfca54f665f411453791c300c7fbd

When I run the query,

```
select *
from geo
where st_distance_sphere(Point(35.0872464,-106.6975887), ST_Centroid(`spatialdata`)) <= 1609*10;
```

I get an error:

> `Error Code: 3617. Latitude -106.646665 is out of range in function st_distance_sphere. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].`

I suppose I need to switch to `Long, Lat` axis order to calculate the distance. How do I do that in `mysql`?

What's a bit confusing is: MySQL has standardized all geometries to `lat-long` axis order. From the docs: `The EPSG has standardized on latitude-longitude order, so all geographic SRSs defined by default in MySQL are latitude-longitude.`

Doc link: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/axis-order-in-spatial-reference-systems/

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of the two constant numbers in the Point object in your query.

```
Point(-106.6975887, 35.0872464)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. To be clear, `ST_Centroid(\`geometry\`)` is of order `POINT(35.08100 -106.64666)` as an example.

Comment: Oh I see. All your geo data -- the stuff you INSERT --  needs the lat and long values to be reversed.

Comment: Yeah, well - mysql standardized the order to `lat-long` though: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/axis-order-in-spatial-reference-systems/

Comment: From the docs: `The EPSG has standardized on latitude-longitude order, so all geographic SRSs defined by default in MySQL are latitude-longitude.`

Comment: @kms Hi, did you solved it? I'm facing the same issue and trying to find the way to make it work. If yes, can you share how you solved it? thanks.